# Parse jsonData and get urlStrings for images in order to implement lazy loading

Tags: java, android, rest, httpclient, lazy-loading

I want to implement a lazy loading image in my ListView. At first I need to connect to a url and get the urlStrings for all images which belong to an object. I get a jsonString and then parse:

```
String RESTUrl = new MasterdataDataProvider(mContext).getSyncServicePath() + "PhotoInfo/" + objectEntryID; 
List<String> urlStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet((RESTUrl + "/" + token));
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    String jsonData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    if (!jsonData.equals("[]")) {
        GsonPhotoInfo x = new GsonPhotoInfo(new GsonBuilder());
        PhotoInfo[] info = x.parseJSON(jsonData);
        for(PhotoInfo p : info) {
            System.out.println(p.getFileName());
            urlStrings.add(photoWebURL + objectDefID + "/" + objectEntryID + "/" + p.getFileName());
        }

   }
} catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you see in this piece of code I fetch the `FileName from jsonData`.

Then I need to download the images from urlStrings:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message message) {
          ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter((Drawable[]) message.obj);
          viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); 
     }
};

     Thread thread = new Thread() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

         //PARSE THE JSON DATA and FETCH URLStrings (as you see in the piece of code at top)                       

         Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[urlStrings.size()];
         for(int i=0; i< urlStrings.size(); i++) 
               drawables[i] = fetchDrawable(urlStrings.get(i));

               Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, drawables);
               handler.sendMessage(message);
         }
    };
    thread.start();
```

The code to fetch image is taken from [James Wilson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview).

So as you can see there as well, I have to use HTTPClient once again to download every image:

```
private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    return response.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

The problem is it is not working in my listView. `The images are not loaded correctly in listView sometimes`, and I am just wondering that is it because of the way that :

1. I get the urlStrings from jsonData, and then
2. Download the images from urlStrings one by one.

I mean I connect to REST two times. I am also using a `Handler` that maybe is not a good option, but actually I tested it with a `AsyncTask` and I had the same problem.

I appreciate for any idea that could solve my problem.

**Addenda:**

I found out images are loaded incorrectly when I scroll in the list very fast, otherwise it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by implementing OnScrollListener for my ListView, and download the image when scroll is in idle mode. But I think the right way is not get the image url in the lazy loading implementation, Maybe the image url need to be included in the main Object.

```
public static boolean scroll_is_idle = true;

mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        switch (scrollState) {
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                    scroll_is_idle = true;
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL: 
                    scroll_is_idle = false;
                    break;
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
                    scroll_is_idle = false;
                    break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UniversalImageLoader` library from [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It pretty much works error free. Does memory handling, threading and all other stuff.

Takes 2 minutes to integrate. Try it out !

Comment: Good to know that, but I am basically want to find the reason that where the problem come from in my code.

Comment: Can you share your ImagePagerAdapter code. Things look fine here !

Comment: https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer/blob/master/src/com/sqisland/android/swipe_image_viewer/MainActivity.java

Comment: The problem is in your `ImagePagerAdapter` since adapters control how view will be displayed on screen. On fast scrolling, the adapters might not be instanting the right element thereby giving an incorrect element. Try reviewing `instantiateItem()` method in  `ImagePagerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy!! you are setting the list adapter every time you download an image. I would suggest you to go with androids tutorial for using a list view and then listview with lazy image loading.

List view

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Image handling

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Where in the code? Setting the viewPage adapter is different from ListView adapter. right?

Comment: Can you make it bit more clear? Where do u use the ImagePagerAdapter?

Comment: https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer/blob/master/src/com/sqisland/android/swipe_image_viewer/MainActivity.java

Comment: Ok. So you are using a ViewPager to display a list of images? If yes, then still my response is valid. You are creating and setting adapter to the viewpager after every image is loaded.

Comment: I am using `Thread`. So the adapter will be set after images are downloaded. Please share some code if you have a better aprroach. (As I said in the question every object can have couple of images.)